# How to add specific names from a column to a new column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe `study` in which there are two columns, `Genes` and `values` like below:

```
dput(study)

structure(list(Genes = c("ERRFI1", "ENO1", "PGD", "DHRS3", "PRDM2", 
"KAZN", "ENSG00000231606", "KAZN-AS1", "XLOC-026476", "FBXO42", 
"XLOC-003972", "MRTO4", "PLA2G2A", "PLA2G5", "ECE1", "ECE1-AS1", 
"RPL11", "YARS1", "AZIN2", "ENSG00000225313", "PHC2", "MACF1"
), values = c(-0.435169319, -0.279902415, -0.599348364, -0.325624659, 
-0.305814597, -1.820893803, -1.670762454, -1.297312265, -0.270233208, 
-0.439544403, -0.341579399, -0.312246797, -1.553644877, -1.721124719, 
-0.775697322, -0.289490274, -0.249540064, -0.292487107, 0.745814452, 
-1.110062984, -0.55023393, 0.568278951)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

I want to create a new column `Genes2` with specific names from `Genes` column.

I tried like below:

```
study$Genes2[study$Genes=="ERRFI1"] <- "ERRFI1"
```

Among the 22 names in `Genes` column I wanted to add 12 names to `Genes2` column. I need to add these to `Genes2` column like above, repeating for every name of those 12 names. Is there any way to do it in one go?

It should look like below:

[image]

Comment: "To do it in one go": Is there a logic behind the cases when you add the name in `genes2`? If not, I think that this is not possible and has to be done manually in the sense that you at least have to supply a list of the names.

Comment: How are you choosing which 12 to copy over? Do you have that list stored in R already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `vector` as `name` and use it to create a new column as below

```r
# vector 
name <- c('ERRFI1','PGD','PRDM2','KAZN','FBXO42')

library(dplyr)

study %>% mutate(Genes2=ifelse(Genes %in% name, Genes, NA_character_))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
             Genes     values Genes2
1           ERRFI1 -0.4351693 ERRFI1
2             ENO1 -0.2799024   <NA>
3              PGD -0.5993484    PGD
4            DHRS3 -0.3256247   <NA>
5            PRDM2 -0.3058146  PRDM2
6             KAZN -1.8208938   KAZN
7  ENSG00000231606 -1.6707625   <NA>
8         KAZN-AS1 -1.2973123   <NA>
9      XLOC-026476 -0.2702332   <NA>
10          FBXO42 -0.4395444 FBXO42
11     XLOC-003972 -0.3415794   <NA>
12           MRTO4 -0.3122468   <NA>
13         PLA2G2A -1.5536449   <NA>
14          PLA2G5 -1.7211247   <NA>
15            ECE1 -0.7756973   <NA>
16        ECE1-AS1 -0.2894903   <NA>
17           RPL11 -0.2495401   <NA>
18           YARS1 -0.2924871   <NA>
19           AZIN2  0.7458145   <NA>
20 ENSG00000225313 -1.1100630   <NA>
21            PHC2 -0.5502339   <NA>
22           MACF1  0.5682790   <NA>
```